# UK VISA Refusal! Submitted All Necessary Documents! (Graduation Ceremony In London)

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

[image: Visa Refusal Reason!]

Now i need to re-apply! what are the steps that i can take to make my application and all documents strong and not get rejeceted.

As per i have my graduation ceremony and i definitaly want to attend it.

Comment: @Syed Hussain Abbas Rizvi You can fix the lack of financial evidence from your sponsor but it’s hard to see how you will overcome your lack of ties to your home country. I’d think hard about whether reapplying is really worth it - two refusals in a row is not a good thing to have on your travel history.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you will get a visa if you are unemployed, single and have a visa rejection to your name. Remember, visas are a privilege, not a right.

Comment: @RodneyHawkins what if i show my employment when i re-apply in a week? I have been employed since past 2 months but i didn't mention this in my visa application as per i just graduated from law school and i was going for my graduation ceremony in London. and i thought u need to show your employment for atleast 6 months or more. Plus my employer is not paying me anything at the moment so there was no point in showing my employment! Right?

Comment: @traveller yes you are right on the basis that i can fix my lack of financial evidence by attaching a good account statement accompanied with my father's 6months payslips/salary slips. right? and as far as ties to your home country are concerned will it be enough to attach Tax Returns/Wealth statements for past 3 years of my father help me? and just to mention that my father will also be accompanying me as per i am still a dependent and rely on him for support for almost everything financially. I also mentioned this in my application and attached my father's UK visa for 2 years & his passport.

Comment: @Syed Hussain Abbas Rizvi Documents relating to your father will not be of any use to prove YOUR ties to your home country. Being dependent and needing a sponsor is a negative when it comes to visa applications - the Immigration rules say you have to qualify in your own right. I agree with Rodney Hawkins, a second application is highly unlikely to succeed unless your circumstances have improved significantly meantime.

Comment: @traveller okay! so how do i prove my strong ties to my home country? as per i just graduated 4 months ago from law school. What if i show my employment when i re-apply in a week? I have been employed since past 2 months but i didn't mention this in my visa application as per i just graduated from law school and i was going for my graduation ceremony in London. and i thought u need to show your employment for at least 6 months or more. Plus my employer is not paying me anything at the moment so there was no point in showing my employment! Right?

Comment: @SyedHussainAbbasRizvi I would not risk reapplying in your current situation. You have a job, but no wage slips, you have been working for only 2 months, and you need a sponsor to pay your trip...

Comment: @gstorto okay but there are several others just like in my position, people i know u also graduated with me and are going to attend their graduation ceremony and have applied just like me... they are also single, unemployed, without pay/salary and they also are being sponsored by their respective father's.... In Pakistan everyone is dependent on their father's or their families until they graduate and become something and are in a state when they start earning... just to clear the fact and to let u know that i am from Pakistan! and the social economic situation is like that over here!